# Grab all elements on a Page and hide a message in them

Tags: javascript, jquery, bit-manipulation, hide, getelementbyid

I'm trying to grab all the elements on my webpage using javascript.  Once I do this I want to hide a message in the elements, probably by LSB.  Right now I'm just trying to hide 'h' which would be 8 bits, which would require 8 elementIDs I think.

My plan is to grab all the IDs.  Use charCodeAt to grab the value of 'h', then hide h's bits in the first 8 elementIDs using bitwise operations on the text size or width field.

I know this is an awful way to hide a message, but I really want to figure this out for learning purposes.  Any ideas on how to do this, or direction would be awesome.

Here is what I have so far...

```
    $(function() {

    //on button click
    // 1. grab LSB  all of elements to be changed
    // 2. change all elements
    // str.charCodeAt(0);
    //var arrayMsg = hideMsg.split("");


    /*

    // 1. maybe grab all elements on the page
    // 2. make a special class with width and text
    // 3. inject all element IDs with this class
    // 4. flip this classes width/text size with LSB of message to hide

    var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    var allIds = [];
    for (var i = 0, n = allElements.length; i < n; ++i) {
      var el = allElements[i];
      if (el.id) { allIds.push(el.id); }
    }

    */

    var hideMsg = "f";
    var n = hideMsg.length;

    var i;
    var j;
    var holder;
    var hideHolder;

    // on button click - hide msg
    $('#btnHide').on('click', function() {

        for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            //set var holder to first value of the message to hide
            holder = hideMsg.charCodeAt(i);

            for(j = 7; -1 < j; j--) {

                //set hideHolder to holders value
                hideHolder = holder;
                //mask hideHolder to grab the first bit to hide
                hideHolder = hideHolder & (1<<j);

                //grab the first element ID

                if(holder === 0) {

                    // embed the bit
                    // bitwise     &= 

                } else {

                    //embed the bit
                    // bitwise ^=
                }

            }

        }


    });

});
```

Comment: How do you want to hide it in the elements? You could add an attribute to each element in which the value is the corresponding bit. To get all elements on a page you could do document.all or document.getElementsByTagName("*").

Comment: I'm open to any suggestions on how to hide.  I was thinking about hiding it in the text-size, like having all text sizes be an EM value such as 1.01, then flipping the 1.01 to 1.00 or keep it as 1.01.   Or maybe hide in the width of a div, the color, or adding a tag property thats not visible and adding the class to all IDs needed with a value to flip or not flip using bitwise ops